# How do I do an http post to code behind in asp.net webforms?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, post, code-behind, webforms

How can I call a method in the code behind from a jQuery post in asp.net webforms?

In MVC it's simple, I just do this:

```
$.post("/MyController/MyMethod", { data: somedata; }, function(result) { alert(result); });
```

but I can't figure how what to put for the first parameter if I wanted to call a method in the code behind in webforms... for example, if I have a method called `doSomething()` is there a way to stick some location in there so that it will call `doSomething()` and return data to the callback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first parameter is just the URL, so you have to expose your code-behind method as a web service.  You can use a page method or a dedicated web service.
Page method example: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=109&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1